# Pivot with 2 columns in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have got this dataframe:

| unnamed: 0 | unnamed: 1 |
| --- | --- |
| B | b |
| C | b |
| D | b |
| E | c |
| F | c |

and I want it to look like this:

| ---------- |
| --- |
| b |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| c |
| E |
| F |

all of my Data are strings and if anyhow possible I would love to highlight the small letters and expand/collaps underneath them.

I was trying to go with the df.pivot_table function:

'''

```
df_pivot_test = pd.read_excel(r'xxxxx.xlsx')

df_pivot_test = df_pivot_test[['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1']]

pivot = df_pivot_test.pivot_table(values='Unnamed: 0',index='Unnamed: 1',aggfunc = lambda x: ','.join(str(v) for v in x)).reset_index()
```

'''

and I get a result with two columns like following:

| unnamed: 1 | unnamed: 0 |
| --- | --- |
| b | B,C,D |
| c | E,F |

I have to program it in python and can't use any other packages.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df['unnamed: 1'].drop_duplicates(),
                 df['unnamed: 0']]).sort_index()
```

Or with a [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = (df.iloc[:, ::-1].stack().reset_index(level=1, name='out')
         .drop_duplicates().drop(columns='level_1')
       )
```

Output:

```
  out
0   b
0   B
1   C
2   D
3   c
3   E
4   F
```

Or based on your original idea of aggregating (but likely inefficient):

```
out = (df.groupby('unnamed: 1', as_index=False)['unnamed: 0']
         .agg(list).stack().explode().droplevel(1)
       )
```

Or a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('unnamed: 1', group_keys=False)['unnamed: 0']
         .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([pd.Series([g.name]), g]))
       )
```

Comment: That's helping me a lot, thank you! My only problem left rn is, when I use concat and than sort it, it sometime mixes up the order.
so it's not defined that the small letter is above those which belong to him.